RecyclerView onDragListeners not working or reacting
Ok, we have a Recycler View inside a fragment, and this Fragment is inside a ViewPager Fragment that includes multiple Fragments.
in one of the Fragments "Create Activity Fragments" we create a Recycler View item as "Task" or in this Context "Activity".
for this item I create a longClickListener for it and start there a "drag and drop".
I move the draged item to the side of the "ViewPager" where I created a "View" that is 20 dp width and used ondraglistener on it to switch the pages of the ViewPager to show the next fragment.
While draging the item.
Here I want to use on Draglistener on the RcyclerView in the Second Fragment. so I can drop that Item inside that Recycler View. or "Move that information from that item to the items in the second RecyclerView".
the RecyclerView is not responding while testing no matter which way I implement the onDragListener.
here is the Code of the Fragment where I use on draglistener and define the on drag method.
private var _fragmentCalenderDayBinding: FragmentCalenderDayBinding? = null
private var rvHours: RecyclerView? = null
var rvEvents: RecyclerView? = null

// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _fragmentCalenderDayBinding!!
private var eventsAdapter: EventsAdapter? = null
private var hoursAdapter: HoursAdapter? = null
var events: MutableList<EventClass> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _fragmentCalenderDayBinding = FragmentCalenderDayBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    val hours : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00")

    eventsAdapter = EventsAdapter(events)
    hoursAdapter = HoursAdapter(hours)

    hours.forEach { _ ->
        var eventClass = EventClass("")
        eventsAdapter!!.addActivity(eventClass)
    }
    rvEvents = _fragmentCalenderDayBinding!!.rvEvents
    rvHours = _fragmentCalenderDayBinding!!.rvHours
    rvEvents?.adapter = eventsAdapter
    rvHours?.adapter = hoursAdapter
    rvEvents?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    rvHours?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
    rvEvents?.setOnDragListener(this)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _fragmentCalenderDayBinding = null
}

override fun onDrag(v: View?, event: DragEvent?): Boolean {
    return when (event?.action) {
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
            event.clipDescription.hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
        }

        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
            rvEvents?.invalidate()
            true
        }

        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
            rvEvents?.background = R.color.pastel_lila.toDrawable()
            true
        }

        DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
            val bindingDialogAskTime: DialogAskTimeBinding =
                DialogAskTimeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(rvEvents?.context ))


            val builder = this.context?.let { androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(it) }

            // set the custom layout
            val customLayout: View = bindingDialogAskTime.root
            builder?.setView(customLayout)

            // add a button
            builder?.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->
                // send data from the AlertDialog to the Activity
                bindingDialogAskTime!!.numberPicker.maxValue = 23
                val chosenHour = bindingDialogAskTime.numberPicker.value
                events[chosenHour].title = event.clipData.toString()
                rvEvents?.invalidate()
            }
            // create and show the alert dialog
            val dialog = builder?.create()
            dialog?.show()
            rvEvents?.invalidate()
            true
        }

        else -> {
            false
        }
    }
}


Your recyclerView not being able to properly handle the drag events because its child views consume the touch events. To enable drag and drop functionality on the recyclerView, you need to set the OnDragListener on each item view within the recyclerView.

@Akshay it doesnt seem to work either, I have implemented the ondraglistner for each recacler View item yet it doesnt work.

do you mind if we connect with a call ?
